# How REST function in Numbers works in Swift

Tags: swift, apple-numbers

In Apple Numbers the `MOD` function differs from Swift (in the German version it is `REST`.

In Numbers:

`4,37937=MOD(−1,90373;6,2831)`

versus

In swift 3:

```
let rem1: Double = -1.90373
let rem = rem1.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 6.28318530717959)
print(rem)
```

`Prints: -1.90373`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
let rem1: Double = -1.90373
let rem = rem1 - 6.28318530717959 * floor(rem1 / 6.28318530717959)
print(rem)
```

will do the same like Apples Numbers `MOD` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

**a % b**  performs the following and returns remainder

```
a = (b x some multiplier) + remainder
```

some multiplier is the largest number of multiples of b that will fit inside a.

e.g. some integer constant [0...]

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) provides the following as an example

> Inserting -9 and 4 into the equation yields:
>
> -9 = (4 x -2) + -1
>
> giving a remainder value of -1.
>
> The sign of b is ignored for negative values of b. This means that a 
>   % b and a % -b always give the same answer.